# Force a field not to be required

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868497/force-a-field-to-not-be-required). But this doesn't help. I've added `'required' => false` but nothing happens.

```
<?php

namespace BN\Bundle\XxBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

    class PersonStudentRegistrationType extends BaseType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
            $builder
                ->add(
                ...
                ...
                )
                ->add(
                    'adresses',
                    'collection',
                    array(
                        'type' => new AdresseType(),
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                        'required' => false
                    )
                )
```

I've made sure that Adresse in entity is nullable:

```
<?php

namespace BN\Bundle\XxBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Adresse
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="adresse")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Adresse
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    //...
    // some other code...
    //...


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse1", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresse1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse2", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresse2;
```

What am I missing? Note: I've followed [this official tutoriel](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) to make dynamic fields (add one or more addresses)

Comment: 'required' => false should do. Maybe you need to clear cache?

Comment: I do it all the time. Both  `php app/console cache:clear` and the "ugly" one: `rm -rf app/cache ; mkdir app/cache && chmod 777 app/cache` (which is often needed whatever the symfony doc says)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the constraint, you should write something like:

```
namespace BN\Bundle\XxBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Adresse
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="adresse")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Adresse
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse1", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Null()
     */
    private $adresse1;

    //...
}
```

Let me know if I'm wrong. Good luck!