# How to disable required for just one UserType and not the other?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

ok, this is starting to drive me up the wall that I can not do this, so heres hoping someone can help!

I am using Symfony 2.3 and I have built up my user form in an 'UserType' class. I have this in two places, one is for when the app adds a new user, which I want the field to stay as it is. However I build a new 'UserType' to view all users, so the app as a management area.

So I want to be able to remove 'required' from my password input on my users form, when a form is just edited, e.g. the email is updated.

From what I have read, this is not doable in twig (which I don't understand why!) but I have to do it in the builder?

1st, is there a way to do this in twig, best option!
2nd, how do I do this to just one of my 'UserTypes' and not the other?

So my code as follows,

**UserType.php**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $RoleOpts = ['ROLE_USER' => 'User','ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'];

        $builder->setMethod('POST');
        $builder->add('username',  'text',    ['label' => 'Username',  'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'Admin_Username']]);
        $builder->add('password',  'password',['label' => 'Password',  'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'Admin_Pswd']]);
        $builder->add('firstname', 'text',    ['label' => 'First Name','attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'Admin_Name']]);
        $builder->add('surname',   'text',    ['label' => 'Surname',   'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'Admin_Surname']]);
        $builder->add('email',     'email',   ['label' => 'Email',     'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'Admin_Email']]);
        $builder->add('userroles', 'choice',  ['label' => 'Role','choices' => $RoleOpts, 'attr' => ['class' => 'Admin_Role']]);
        $builder->add('save',      'submit',  ['label' => 'Save User', 'attr' => ['class' => 'Admin_SaveUser']]);
    }
```

**ViewUsers Action**

```
public function ViewUsersAction() {
    $GetAllUsers = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getRepository('Bundle:Users')
                     ->findAll();

    foreach($GetAllUsers as $UserKey => $UserValue) {
        $UserID = $UserValue->getId();

        $ViewAllUsers[$UserKey] = $this->createForm(new UserType(), 
                                                    $GetAllUsers[$UserKey],
                                                    ['action' => $this->generateUrl('Admin_EditUser', ['id' => $UserID])]
                                                    )->createView();
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Admin:Users/view.html.twig', ['ViewUsers' => $ViewAllUsers ]);
}
```

**Twig File**

```
   {% for View in ViewUsers %}

    {{ form_start(View, {'attr': {'class': 'EditUser'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(View) }}

        {{ form_row(View.username, {'attr': {'disabled': 'disabled'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(View.password, {'attr': {'required': false}}) }}
        {{ form_row(View.firstname) }}
        {{ form_row(View.surname) }}
        {{ form_row(View.email) }}
        {{ form_row(View.userroles) }}

        {{ form_row(View.save, { 'label': 'Update User' }) }}

    {{ form_end(View) }}

{% endfor %}
```

I have read, [Force a field to not be required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868497/force-a-field-to-not-be-required), but that adds it to the builder, which would change both add new user, and edit all users, which i don't want!

Any help, please?

*If I have forgotten any code or other sections you need to see, please let me know!

Comment: In case you do not get an answer to your question, could you not create two functions for the builder, one for editing and one for adding? I don't use symfony but that seems like something that would be doable. That way in your main builder function you can call `buildEdit` or `buildUpdate` accordingly

Comment: Umm, not sure, I am still a little new to symfony. But I think, that would make the fact that it's a class a little pointless? I would them have two forms, ok in the same file, but if the user table changed, I would still have to change both :)

Comment: that's why I said _if_ no one answers your question. It is a temporary solution, definitely not ideal :)

Comment: Yeah, It would be a good idea for a fast fix, if I could get it to work :) - I was thinking I little differently. I think, that I could just render the user edit form by html in the template, rather than get twig to render it! But I am not sure about that, think your idea is better :)

Comment: what about a conditional in Twig for the password field? `if edit then not_required else required`

Comment: I am using a edit template and a add new template, so that's not important but thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with the validation groups?

Comment: Could you point me to where are in the docs? I think I looked at them but not sure if that did what was needed, could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

**Step one** is to write a default option in the ***setDefaultOptions*** method.
**Step two** is to use the option in the ***buildForm*** method:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...

        $builder->add('password',  'password',['required' => $options['password_required']]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'password_required' => TRUE
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_user';
    }
}
```

**step three** is to call the ***createForm*** method from your ***editAction*** or ***createEditForm*** method (or in your case your ViewUsersAction) with an extra option which is 'password_required' => FALSE:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'password_required' => FALSE
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I give that a go. Plus extra for also showing me how to change the method to PUT!

Comment: I gave your answer a go, but it did not work, got the following error "The option "password_required" does not exist.". So I change the option to just 'required'. That sort of worked, but what it did was remove required from all my inputs apart from password!

Answer (score 0):

It might differ in v2.3, as im not sure if this is already supported, but you could add an event listener on The pre-set-data event. Here you can check if the given data (your entity) in the builder has an id or not. When it has one, you are editting the data. If it has no id, you are adding a new user. So with this info, you could easily remove the required option.

There is lots of info on this at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Thanks, I think I looked at that, but could not see how, PRE_SET_DATA (think thats the best option) could work but with what you say, by checking for an id, then yes I think that could work, I look into it, thanks